# function returns NaN when the index of arrays are defined through a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm doing a project, and this function returns `NaN`. The last time I had this problem, I fixed it by defining a variable that was equal to 0. However it doesn't work.

```js
var avstandArray = [
  [0, 62.3, 58.8, 44.6, 33.2],
  [62.3, 0, 37.9, 65.3, 60.1],
  [58.8, 37.9, 0, 40.5, 78.5],
  [44.6, 65.3, 40.5, 0, 77.6],
  [33.2, 60.1, 78.5, 77.6, 0]
]

var reiserute = [0, 1];

function ruteFunction() {
  var z = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < reiserute.length; i++) {
    z += avstandArray[reiserute[i]][reiserute[i + 1]];
  }
  return z;
}

console.log(ruteFunction());
```

Comment: `reiserute.length` is an empty array.what s the expected output?

Comment: @brk for example `var reiserute = [0, 1];`then the expected output would be 62.3

Comment: Your function currently returns 0, because `reiserute` is empty.

Comment: @JLRishe actually i've pushed in some values. but i haven't added the codes to this question since i thought it is not important. i would like to assume the array is for example [0, 1]

Comment: Why would you expect the result `62.3` when `reiserute` is `[0, 1]`? What is the significance of `reiserute`?

Comment: @Shinji It's very important to give us a way to reproduce the issue, especially since you haven't explained what the code is supposed to do or how you expect it to work.

Comment: While you can't see the issue when `reiserute` is empty - because the loop won't even run - you are going to get `NaN` whenever it isn't empty. This is because you are accessing `reiserute[i + 1]` even when `i` is `reiserute.length - 1`, which is going to be `undefined`. Looks like you should stop your loop one interation earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The head of your loop is as follows:

`for (var i = 0; i < reiserute.length; i++)`

This means that `i` will vary from `0` up to `reiserute.length - 1`, inclusive.

Then, in your loop body, you do this:

`z += avstandArray[reiserute[i]][reiserute[i + 1]];`

Note in particular the `reiserute[i + 1]`. Since `i` is running from `0` to `reiserute.length - 1`, `i + 1` will range from `1` to `reiserute.length`. So on the last iteration you are trying to access `reiserute[reiserute.length]`. And this will be `undefined` - you are trying to access an index "one beyond" the end of the array.

So you are then evaluating

`avstandArray[reiserute[i]][undefined]`

which is itself `undefined`. Then `+=` forcibly coerces this to a `Number`, which is where your `NaN` comes from.

While I'm not sure what the exact intention behind your code is, the easiest fix would be to change the header of your loop to not access elements beyond the last in the array. That is, do this instead:

`for (var i = 0; i < reiserute.length - 1; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
z+= avstandArray[reiserute[i]][reiserute[i+1]];
```

the above code will try to get the value from reiserute array at n+1th element which is undefined and adding the undefined element to number will throw NaN exception. So Change the logic accordingly.

```
for (var i = 0; i < reiserute.length; i++) {
if(i!=reiserute.length)
    z+= avstandArray[reiserute[i]][reiserute[i+1]];
else
    z+= avstandArray[reiserute[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is returning 0 without any issues. As you defined `var reiserute = [];` the for loop not even running for once.

```js
var avstandArray = [
[0, 62.3, 58.8, 44.6, 33.2],
[62.3, 0, 37.9, 65.3, 60.1],
[58.8, 37.9, 0, 40.5, 78.5],
[44.6, 65.3, 40.5, 0, 77.6],
[33.2, 60.1, 78.5, 77.6, 0]
]

var reiserute = [0,1];

function ruteFunction(){
var z = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < reiserute.length; i++) {
    z+= avstandArray[reiserute[i]][reiserute[i+1]];
    console.log(z);
}
return z;
}

console.log(ruteFunction());
```

Comment: i have defined it earlier. but let's assume the array consists of 0 and 1

Comment: Edited the code. check... your i+1 causing NAN coz at the second iteration there is no index available.

Comment: WHat exactly you want the function to return. please explain and I'll update the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, although, this is the issue:

your "reiserute" variable has no value in it, it is an empty array and you are trying to access value at different indexes, since there is no data available, javascript will return "undefined".

```
reiserute[i] ----> undefined
```

now you are trying to find a value passing reiserute[i], which essentially is undefined.
when you try to access a value of an array using an index, javascript expects your index to be an integer, since your index was evaluated to undefined, it threw NaN error - Nan stands for "NotANumber".

now, you are getting your output as "0" because, length of the array is zero and condition is failing in the first check, hence the loop is not executed.

If your loop executes, you will receive NaN as an error.

Comment: the thing is i already defined earlier from some codes i didn't add here since i didn't think it would be necessary.

Comment: but in this code it is reset to an empty array, all your previous values are lost